# Why don't substances other than water ice show regelation?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, ice

We know that ice shows [regelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regelation),but why don't other substances like iron rods or wood show the same phenomenon? Is there something special about ice?

Comment: Have you tried starting with [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regelation)? It states that regelation "occurs only for substances such as ice, that have the property of expanding upon freezing". Is this unclear? If so, what parts are unclear?

Comment: Means , if the substance which also has property  to expand on freezing can show regelation?

Comment: Other such substances would, yes, but they're not numerous. They certainly don't include iron or wood. (Can you even melt wood without it burning?)

Comment: There are a half dozen elements that expand on freezing, and who knows now many alloys or compounds. Ice is the one we all know of, since freezing occurs at human-friendly temperatures (unlike, say, silicon).